# How to add "..." on a trimmed string?

Tags: java, android, string, text, trim

I've set the maxLength of the string to 100, so I need that the first 97 characters are normal chars, but the last three have to be "...".

Tried to add +"..." to the string, but, naturally, when it reaches the limit, nothing can be added there.

How to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't mentioned why are you trimming the String. 
If you are trimming it to use it in TextView/Button/etc, don't forget you can use maxLines and ellipsize to achieve desired effect.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

(If I am wrong and this has nothing to do with TextViews, just ignore this answer :))

Comment: I'm sorry for not being so specifical on those terms, but that's the answer I was looking for! :) Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

A solution that copes with strings of all length:

```
String trim(String string, int maxLength)
{
    if (maxLength < 3)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Max length (" + maxLength + ") must at least 3");

    return string.length() > maxLength ? 
               string.substring(0, maxLength - 3) + "..." : 
               string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#substring` as follows:

```
int maxLength = 100;
String lastThree = "...";
return str.substring(0, maxLength - lastThree.length()) + "...");
```

A working example:

```
public class Test {
    static final String str = "redgreenblue";
    static final String t = "...";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(str.substring(0,10-t.length()) + t);
        }
        catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println(str + t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this on short strings. It will throw an Exception.

Comment: No it doesn't (unless the string itself is shorter than "..."). I copy-pasted it from a working test. Adding the test code to my answer now.

Comment: Try it on *short* strings. [".. throws IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) The [Android documentation has similar wording](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)).

Comment: Just wondering ... why are you focusing on short strings at all? Just append "..." for them. Your question is about long strings that go beyond 100, right?

Comment: -1. This approach is broken, for the reason mentioned above and will fail on some input strings "unexpectedly". Either, *accept* this and *fix the answer*, provide a *good* counter argument, or at least *mention* the issue in the answer.

Comment: Your code should cope with string of any length.  Why assume that the string is always over 3 characters?

Comment: Fine ... added a try-catch to handle this.

Comment: @ChthonicProject It's not an "Exceptional" situation and should not involve Exception handling :-/ Your approach is *almost* okay, it just needs a conditional check first to guard the case (and it could also allow for only adding "..." when needed).

Comment: @ChthonicProject Anyway, I've removed my -1 (although I still think the approach needs revisiting) and - if you are using Exception handling, which I don't recommend - you'll want to catch `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (no String at the start).

Comment: @user2864740 : I am grateful, to say the least.

Comment: I prefer catching the most specific exception ... it's a better practice, in my opinion. `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a subclass of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Here's the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should almost always use a `StringBuilder` when putting a string together. In this case, you can call `setCharAt()` to change the last three characters. If you really really do need to use a `String` directly, use `substring()` to capture the first 97 characters and then add the ellipsis.